# Covariance of three conditional Gaussians that are products of each other

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, covariance-matrix

I have three conditional Gaussians

$\mathbb{P}(A|B,C) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left  \{ -\frac{1}{2} (A -BC)^2    \right \}$

$\mathbb{P}(B|A,C) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left  \{ -\frac{1}{2} (B -AC)^2    \right \}$,

$\mathbb{P}(C|A,B) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left  \{ -\frac{1}{2} (C -AB)^2    \right \}$,

so $\mu_A = \mathbb{E}[A] = BC, \mu_B = \mathbb{E}[B] = AC$ , and $\mu_C = \mathbb{E}[C] = AB.$

Now I factorize these conditional distributions to a joint distribution F = ABC, and I would like to compute the covariance matrix of F.

From simulations I see that all covariances are equal to zero. But I have trouble deriving it. If I start with $Cov(A, B) = \mathbb{E}[AB] = \mathbb{E}[BCB]$ and so on I don't get anywhere because no pair is independent.

Comment: One attractive approach is to begin with the partial covariances, such as the covariance between $A$ and $B$ conditional on $C$.